# Java, when I put my User in a Map, it's not working

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, gson

I'm developing two api for a minecraft server, a proxy, and a spigot, when a player connects, the proxy API fetches the player on the database, then sends it on redis, then the api spigot will look for the player on redis, and save it in a Map, and that's where the problem is, I have a "User#get" method like this:

```
public static User get(UUID uuid) {
    return users.getOrDefault(uuid, fetchUser(uuid));
}
```

And a "User#fetchUser" like this:

```java
private static User fetchUser(UUID uuid) {
    return Main.instance.getRedisAPI().get(uuid.toString(), User.class);
}
```

The key redis is the uuid of the player, and the value, is the user class serialized in JSON, with the api Gson
I recently knew that Gson, to deserialize, created his own empty constructor, and filled the fields by reflection, which I do not want, because it is in my constructor that I put the User in the map. So I created my own TypeAdapter that implements JsonDeserializer, in order to run the constructor. it works, the constructor is well executed, but the user is not put in the map! So every time I make a User#get, it runs the fetchUser, and it ends up crashing because it's too many requests. I'm putting my classes in a pastebin for you to watch. (sorry if that's not the way to do it, it's the first time I'm posting on stackoverflow, and sorry for my english, I'm french and I use google translation)

User.java > https://pastebin.com/4ta4XDqX 
RedisAPI.java > https://pastebin.com/GjWPUf4m 
Serializer.java > https://pastebin.com/k6g1KYYF 
UserDeserializer.java > https://pastebin.com/0LF7trSR

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit into the question the minimal code necessary to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Map::getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) does:

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or defaultValue if this map contains no mapping for the key.

So, it does not add any value to the map at all. You're also always eagerly executing the `User::fetchUser` method, whether the `UUID` exists in the map or not.

It sounds like you need [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) instead, which:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null.

i.e.

```
public static User get(UUID uuid) {
    return users.computeIfAbsent(uuid, User::fetchUser);
}
```

Where `User::fetchUser` is only executed if the `UUID` was not found in the map already.

Comment: I add my user in the map in the User constructor, so, if I execute users.getOrDefault, its gonna return the User in the map, and if the User is not in the Map, its gonna execute the fetchUser, and the fetch User is gonna execute the constructor, and in the constructor, I put the user in the map, you can see it un User.java, the problem is: the Map::put of the constructor doesn't working..

Comment: @OpperDev it doesn't matter whether the user is in the map or not! Before `users.getOrDefault` can be called Java has to determine the values of both parameters of that method. The second parameter value is the result of `fetchUser(uuid)`. So Java always (unconditionally) calls `fetchUser(uuid)`

Comment: @OpperDev I see what you mean. Well, with the `putIfAbsent` approach you could remove the `put` call from the constructor as well.

Comment: So instead of putting a put in my constructor, I put a putIfAbsent?
And in my get method, I put `return users.containsKey(uuid) ? users.get(uuid) : fetchUser(uuid);` ?

Comment: @OpperDev exactly, with `putIfAbsent` the `fetchUser` method is only called if the user is absent and the method will put the user into the map too.

Comment: @OpperDev `return users.containsKey(uuid) ? users.get(uuid) : fetchUser(uuid);` has the same effect as `return computeIfAbsent(uuid, User::fetchUser)`, except that it does not put the user in the map. What I mean is; remove `put`/`computeIfAbsent` from the constructor altogether, and just have the `computeIfAbsent` in the `get` method (like shown in the answer). Sorry, I meant `computeIfAbsent` before, not `putIfAbsent`.